# How to replace CSS rule with another for some class?

Tags: html, css, styles

For example I have this CSS rule:

```css
.dataList table {
  width: 100%;
}

.dataList table.onlyThisTables {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dataList">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Content of this table
        <table class="onlyThisTables">
          <tr>
            <td>Content of this table
              <td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But always get `width:100%;` in all tables, I want to affect with `400px` width for `.onlyThisTables` class, How can I do it?

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Can you show us an example HTML code where it does not behave like you would expect it? Hard to tell the mistake if we don't see where you apply the `onlyThisTables` class (it has to be on the table).

Comment: Are your tables descendants of an element with the class `dataList`, or do the tables have the class `dataList`?

Comment: CSS is ok, make sure you are using a table with class="onlyThisTables" (is case sensitive)

Comment: @j08691 yes is for table descendants, I believe there's the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: @Marvin there is the HTML example now

Comment: I put your updated code in a stack snippet and the inner table appears to be the correct width.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

To solve your updated question you can use `!important` suffix:

```
.dataList  table {
  width: 100%;
}

.dataList .onlyThisTables {
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lksv4dnd/

Comment: Haha. Touché, @yev.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your html structure. Could you put an example of the html code?
Probably the answer is:

```
.dataList table {
width:100%;
}
.onlyThisTables {
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `max-width` in your styles:

```
.dataList table {
  width: 100%;
}

.dataList table.onlyThisTables {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```